# Rank of a composition of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose there exist linear transformations, $g:V \rightarrow W$ and $h:W \rightarrow X$, and define $f = h \circ g$. I'd like to ask how do we show the following:

1. if $g$ is an epimorphism, then $\rho (f) = \rho (h)$
2. if $h$ is a monomorphism, then $\rho (f) = \rho (g)$

where $\rho (f) = rank (f)$, $\rho (g) = rank (g)$, $\rho (h) = rank (h)$.

Here's what I did:

I know that if $g$ is an epimorphism, then $\rho (g) = dim W$ [1]. But we also have the following results based on the rank-nullity theorem,

- $dim V = \nu(f) + \rho(f)$ [2]
- $dim W = \nu(h) + \rho(h)$ [3]
- $dim V = \nu(g) + \rho(g)$ [4]

Thus,

$\nu(f) + \rho(f) = \nu(g) + \rho(g)$ equating [2] and [4]

$\nu(f) + \rho(f) = \nu(g) + \nu(h) + \rho(h)$ substituting [1]

How do we show that $\nu(f) = \nu(g) + \nu(h)$ ?

Also, if $h$ is a monomorphism, then $dim W = \rho(h)$ because $ker (h) = {0_W}$ and thus, $\nu(h) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $g$ is an epimorphism,
Than $g$ is surjective and hence $g(V)=W$, implying that $f(V)=h(g(V))=h(W)$ , so $\rho (f)=\rho (h)$.
Suppose h is a monomorphism,
And let $\hat h$ be the limitation of $h$ on $g(V)$. Then since h is injective, $\hat h$ is injective and we get: $\rho (f)=dim(f(V))=dim(h(g(V))=dim(\hat h(g(V)))=dim(g(V))=\rho(g)$.